# How to change control from async function to main code back to async function?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Is it possible to change the control from one async function to another or from one async function to a sync function?

```py
import asyncio

def main():
  print("Beginning")
  asyncio.run(async_func())
  print ("Middle")
  print("End")

async def async_func():
  print(1)
  await asyncio.sleep(1) 
  # I want to print "Middle" during this
  print(2)
  await asyncio.sleep(1) 
  # I want to print "End" during this
  print(3)

main()
```

Comment: Why not put the `print("Middle")` inside `async_func` then? Or break it up into two separate functions so that you can run code in between calling them?

Comment: That's just an example. It's not a problem I am facing or anything. The real question is if and how can I transfer control from one async function to another while one is not running?

Comment: You can't. Apart from control structures, statements in a function are still executed top to bottom. Async doesn't change that. You can't "transfer control" to the middle of another function.

Comment: Oh okay that answers my question I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Apart from control structures, statements in a function are still executed top to bottom. Async doesn't change that. You can't "transfer control" to the middle of another function.